# Read Columns using Sheetfu

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to read data from sheetfu from python, i tried gspread but was getting constant (Not sufficient authentication) messages.

So i used sheetfu and it seems to work great, i can retrieve all the values just fine.

I can't figure out how to retrieve values for a specific column into an array.

https://github.com/socialpoint-labs/sheetfu

I'm using Python 3.7.0

I tried printing as a table to see if i could manipulate it that way, with no joy... :(

This is what i have for now, which gives me all the values, but i can't seem to work out how to just show those results for a particular column,

```
from sheetfu import SpreadsheetApp
from sheetfu import Table

def main():

  spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp('/Users/myuser/Downloads/myJson.json').open_by_id('randomspreadsheetID')
  sheet = spreadsheet.get_sheet_by_name('data')
  data_range = sheet.get_data_range()

  values = data_range.get_values()
  print(values)


#   data_range2 = spreadsheet.get_sheet_by_name('data').get_data_range()

#   table = Table(data_range2, backgrounds=True)

#   for item in table:
#       who = item.get_field_value('Who?')

#   table.commit()
#   print(who)
#   print(table)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

This is the return i get.

`['Name', 'Date', 'Who', 'What', 'When', 'Why', 'Where', 'Confirmed', 'Ticked', 'Notes', 'Complete'], ['Dave ', 43627, 'Here', 'Collection','pm', 'no', 'boom', 'lhi', False, '', ''],`

I suppose i could manipulate the text around the [] for each row, and then split, but i was imaging the library would be able to handle this.

Comment: Only saw the question now. Apologies. Author of Sheetfu here. Looking at your commented code, sonething does not add up. PM, if you need some more details.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a list comprehension to do that. From your code:

```py
from sheetfu import SpreadsheetApp
from sheetfu import Table

def main():
    spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp('/Users/myuser/Downloads/myJson.json').open_by_id('randomspreadsheetID')
    sheet = spreadsheet.get_sheet_by_name('data')
    data_range = sheet.get_data_range()

    table = Table(data_range)
    everyone = [item.get_field_value('Who?') for item in table]
    print(everyone)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

This will effectively returns a list of values for the column 'Who?'.